# Getting cells in a 2D grid between two angles

Tags: math, grid, vector-graphics, angle, raycasting

[image]

I've implemented a basic raycasting algorithm successfully, but I want to expand it to work with "angle ranges".

Knowing grid cell size, number of columns and rows, starting ray position, angle a and angle b, how can I get all the cells that fall between the two rays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both rays lie in the same quadrant or in neighbour quadrants:

You can use slightly modified [Bresenham algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to walk both rays together in parallel and get whole column or row of cells between them. Example pseudocode for the case of your example and for (mostly) horizontal sector:

```
 initialisation for deltaerr1, deltaerr2
 for x from 0 to EndXCoord
         get all cells in column (x,y1)-(x,y2)

         error1 := error1 + deltaerr1
         if error1 ≥ 0.5 then
             y1 := y1 + 1
             error1 := error1 - 1.0

         error2 := error2 + deltaerr2
         if error2 ≥ 0.5 then
             y2 := y2 + 1
             error2 := error2 - 1.0
```

If the rays are in opposite quadrants, then walk them apart (and take all intermediate quadrant)

Some cases:

1st and 2nd quadrants: make steps in y-direction, get rows

1st and 4th quadrants: make steps in x-direction ,get columns (as in pseudocode)

start in the 1st and end angle in 3rd quadrants: make steps in y-direction in each quadrant, get all needed cells in the 2nd quadrant

special cases:

some angle is n*90 - it may be necessary to change direction

rays make a 180° angle: do Bresenham steps along the line in needed range, get rows or columns in selected semi-plane

Comment: Good idea. I understand how to do it for one quadrant, but I'm confused on how I should handle different quadrants, or a situation where a ray is in a quadrant and the other ray is in another quadrant.
What if the rays make a 180° angle? How can I "walk" the inner cells for the quadrants in the middle?

Comment: @Vee Some more thoughts added